# Is this function twice differentiable at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have a function $f(x)$:

$$f(x)=\frac{\exp(-|x|)}{1-0.5|\tanh(2x)|}$$

If I try differentiating it in Mathematica (taking $|x|=(2\theta(x)-1)x$ where $\theta(x)$ is Heaviside step function), I get answer in terms of Heaviside functions. But looking at the derivative I can't really see any jump there, which is why I start thinking that it has a second derivative too. But differentiating once more, I get answer with Dirac functions, which don't disappear when evaluating the result at $x=0$.

If I instead represent $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, then for the first derivative I get an expression which has $0$ as its limit as $x\to0$, and for second derivative the limit appears to be 1. So from this I could make the conclusion that $f(x)$ *is* twice differentiable at $x=0$.

So the question: is this function differentiable at $x=0$? Is it *twice* differentiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are dealing with real $x$ (we are, aren't we?), we can write

$$\lvert \tanh (2x)\rvert = \tanh (2\lvert x\rvert).$$

We have $\frac12\tanh (2\lvert x\rvert) = \lvert x\rvert + O(\lvert x\rvert^3)$, so we can calculate

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{-\lvert x\rvert}}{1 - \frac12\tanh(2\lvert x\rvert)} &= \left(1 - \lvert x\rvert + \frac{\lvert x\rvert^2}{2} + O(\lvert x\rvert^3)\right)\left(1 + \lvert x\rvert + \lvert x\rvert^2 + O(\lvert x\rvert^3)\right)\\
&= 1 + \frac{\lvert x\rvert^2}{2} + O(\lvert x\rvert^3).
\end{align}$$

Since the two halves of the function are analytic, it follows that the function is twice continuously differentiable.

Generally, if we have a function of the form

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}g(x) &, x \geqslant 0\\ h(x) &, x \leqslant 0 \end{cases}$$

where $g$ and $h$ are continuously differentiable functions with $g(0) = h(0)$ - so that the definition of $f$ has no conflict - then $f$ is differentiable in $0$ if and only if $g'(0) = h'(0)$, and then $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f'(0) = g'(0) = h'(0)$.

If $g$ and $h$ are analytic, i.e. we have power series representations

$$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n,\qquad h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n,$$

then $f$ is $k$ times (continuously) differentiable if and only if $a_n = b_n$ for $0 \leqslant n \leqslant k$. The computation above shows that the two functions

$$g(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{1-\frac12\tanh(2x)}\quad\text{and}\quad h(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+\frac12\tanh(2x)}$$

both have power series expansions starting with $1 + \frac12 x^2$, so $f$ is twice continuously differentiable.

Comment: Nope. $\tanh$ is an odd function, and $\tanh x > 0$ for $x > 0$, so $\lvert \tanh x\rvert = \tanh \lvert x\rvert$.

Comment: That's true. My typo$\ldots$  Thanks.

Comment: Since a second-order Taylor approximation does not imply that the function is twice differentiable (unlike order one is equivalent to differentiability), maybe a few more details would be needed ;-)

Comment: @julien Would you consider merely referring to the analyticity of both halves sufficient, or would you advise elaborating more?

Comment: I might be blind but I can't see why this is clearly analytic. But for all $x$ non zero (doing $x$ positive and negative separately), we have $f'(x)=\frac{\exp(-|x|)(2 \tanh(2|x|)+4\sech^2(2|x|)-4) }{(2-\tanh(2|x|))^2}$ and we can easily look at the limit of $(f'(x)-f'(0))/(x-0)=f'(x)/x$ from there. Which is indeed $1$.

Comment: @julien $f$ is of course not analytic. But the two halves $\dfrac{e^{-x}}{1-\frac12\tanh(2x)}$ ($x \geqslant 0$) and $\dfrac{e^x}{1+\frac12\tanh(2x)}$ ($x \leqslant 0$) are. And they fit together to the second order.

Comment: Right. I misunderstood. Your argument is the shortest path. +1.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\large\tt Hint:$
\begin{align}
\verts{\tanh\pars{2x}} &= \tanh\pars{2\verts{x}}
\\[3mm]
\verts{\tanh\pars{2x}}\,'
&=
\sech^{2}\pars{2\verts{x}}
\bracks{2\sgn\pars{x}}
=
2\sgn\pars{x}\sech^{2}\pars{2x}
\\[5mm]
\verts{\tanh\pars{2x}}\,''
&=
2\delta\pars{x}\sech^{2}\pars{2x} + 2\sgn\pars{x}
\bracks{-4\tanh\pars{2x}\sech^{2}\pars{2x}}
\\[3mm]&=
2\delta\pars{x} - 8\tanh\pars{2\verts{x}}\sech^{2}\pars{2x}
\\[5mm]
\pars{\expo{-\verts{x}}}' &= -\sgn\pars{x}\expo{-\verts{x}}
\\[3mm]
\pars{\expo{-\verts{x}}}'' &= -2\delta\pars{x}\expo{-\verts{x}}
-
\sgn\pars{x}\expo{-\verts{x}}\bracks{-\sgn\pars{x}}
=
-2\delta\pars{x} + \expo{-\verts{x}}
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry but this is not mathematics, even as hints.